# Get thumbnail image URL for Video

Tags: 7, views, files

I've got a Video field and the Video Thumbnail is uploaded by the user.

I've got a View which is generating JSON (with the views_datasource extension). I want to include the image url to the Video Thumbnail has one of the fields in my JSON. I've set the formatter on this field to be "Video Thumbnail":

[image]

However, the value shown in my JSON output is the url to the original video and not to the Thumbnail image.

So, I tried enabling Rewriting on that field in the Views configuration. I used the `[field_video-thumbnail]` token to try to get the URL of the Thumbnail image...

[image]

but what I get in my JSON is the fid of the Image and not the URL of the image.

```
  "node" : {
    "title" : "Test 6",
    "body" : "<p>test</p>\n",
    "field_image" : null,
    "path" : "/blog/test-6",
    "created" : "Monday, November, 2012",
    "field_video" : "38"
  }
```

How can I get the Image Thumbnail URL?

Comment: dont rewrite output and choose option "link video thumbnail" to url

Comment: When I do that it just generates a link to the Video and not the Thumbnail Image.

Comment: what options are in "link video thumbnail" ?

Comment: "Nothing" "File" and "Content". I tried them all and didn't get any good results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php views, add php field  and put this code (change the video field name to yours) in output part

```
<?php
$file=file_load($data->field_field_video[0]['raw']['thumbnail']);
print file_create_url($file->uri);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module.